# Отчего возникает ошибка при клике на dom element (AngularJS)?

Tags: angularjs

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Когда кликаю на кнопку, мне нужно чтобы в другом месте появлялся текст этой кнопки, но выводится ошибка постоянная

```
<div class="col-content">
      <div class="blc title">{{ title.proccess }}</div>

      <span class="blc" ng-repeat="process in processess" ng-click="processCreate($event, process)" data-id="{{ process.id }}" data-enable="false">
        <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>
        <span class="p-left" >{{ process.caption }}</span>
      </span>

    </div>

 <div class="col-content">
      <div class="blc maintitle">{{ title.namecontent }}</div>
    </div>
```

введите сюда описание изображения введите сюда описание изображения Когда кликаю на кнопку, мне нужно чтобы в другом месте появлялся текст этой кнопки, но выводится ошибка постоянная

```
 // когда кликаем по кнопке
 $scope.processCreate = function(event, process){

    var id = process.id; 
    var caption = process.caption; 

    $('[data-id]').removeClass('active');
    $('[data-id=' + id+']').addClass('active');

    $scope.title.namecontent = caption;
    $scope.$apply();


}
```

Comment: блин, тупо убрать надо $scope.$apply();

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка из-за использования [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) внутри функции обработчика.

Любое взаимодействие с пользователем запускает `digest` цикл и при попытке запустить его еще раз, с помощью `$apply` оканчивается указанной ошибкой

<sub>стоит определиться использовать ангуляр или все-таки jQuery, если нужно добавить убрать класс, лучше воспользоваться директивой `ng-class`</sub>